# How to round time to nearest hour in spoon pentaho

Tags: pentaho-spoon, spool

I have a datetime field in this format "*dd/MM/yyyy, HH:mm:ss*".

I nedd to get the nearest up hour using **spoon tranformation options**.

Any suggestion?

For example:
Original date and time object: 10/08/2021, 15:51:25
Date and Time in Integer Format: 10/08/2021, 16:00:00

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Modified JavaScript value` step to round time to the nearest hour using JS and then use the `Select values` step to format the date.

```
function roundToHour(date) {
  p = 60 * 60 * 1000; // milliseconds in an hour
  return new Date(Math.round(date.getTime() / p ) * p);
}

var new_dt = roundToHour(dt);

var new_dt_fmt = roundToHour(dt);
```

[image: demo]